# ¿Cómo puedo recargar un DataGridView desde otro formulario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tengo el siguiente problema con mi proyecto:

Tengo un formulario 1 donde veo tickets que sacaron turnos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago click sobre llamar una vez seleccionado el registro, guarda la información dentro de una tabla.

Este otro formulario levanta en ese grid la información al iniciar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta seria, ¿como puedo lograr actualizar la tabla del formulario 2 cada vez que yo inserte datos desde el formulario 1?

Gracias de antemano.

UPDATE.

He intentado con lo que mencionaron de usar un método desde el formulario 2 e invocarlo y usarlo en el uno, pero sigo sin obtener resultados, el método funciona dado que cuando lo uso en el formulario 2 con un Load apenas levanta, trae todos los datos, pero cuando en el formulario 1 lo agrego al evento de click en llamar, no actualiza la grilla del form 2, si lo cierro y lo vuelvo a levantar si los trae.
Es necesario que el form 2 siempre quede abierto, así que es imposible cerrarlo y abrirlo por cada vez que necesite actualizar los datos.

Código en formulario 2:

```
public partial class Llamador: Form {
    public Llamador() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    Controles con = new Controles();

    public void UpdatearCosas() {
      con.CargarTurnosLlamados(dgvLlamador);
    }
```

Y este es el código del formulario 1 invocando el método antes creado.

```
private void btnLlamar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Controles con = new Controles();

  TurnosLlamados turnosallamar = new TurnosLlamados();

  int idserv = Convert.ToInt32(cmbServicio.SelectedValue);

  turnosallamar.Id_Puesto = Convert.ToInt32(cmbPuestos.SelectedValue);

  turnosallamar.NroTurno = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvTurnos.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);

  con.LlamarTurno(turnosallamar);

  int id = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvTurnos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);

  con.CambiarEstado(id);
  con.cargargrillaTurnos(dgvTurnos, idserv);
  Llamador llama = new Llamador();
  llama.UpdatearCosas();
}
```

Pero el método sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Si no quieres tener que cerrar el `formulario2` y volver a dar click en `Llamar` una opción es usar eventos. Así desde el `formulario1` lanzas un evento al que te suscribes desde el `formulario2` y cada vez que lo recibas actualizas la info.

Comment: Otra es si desde `formulario1` tienes acceso al `formulario2` solamente crea e invoca un método en el `formulario2`, ej: `UpdateInfo()`, cada vez que quieras actualizarlo.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a Data Binding. Es una forma de tener datos centralizados de los que pueden "beber" los distintos formularios y controles de la aplicación. Cuando los cambias en un lugar, todo lo que hayas conectado se actualiza automáticamente. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/15652/data-binding https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview

Answer (score 1):

Lo que queres hacer es correcto, pero esta mal.

El `form`, no es mas que otro objeto. Y como todo objeto, tiene instancias.

El `form`, es un objeto particular ya que ademas de propiedades y metodos, se "dibuja". Pero eso no hace que no funcione como un objeto comun.

Entonces, cuando haces esto:

```
Llamador llama = new Llamador();
llama.UpdatearCosas();
```

Esta mal, porque definitivamente, ese nuevo `form`, no es el mismo que estas mostrando por pantalla.

Lo que vos tenes que hacer es llamar al metodo `UpdatearCosas`, pero del `form` que vos abriste en su momento.

Comment: Entiendo la lógica, ¿pero como sabría que instancia es?
El caso es el siguiente, el formulario 1 es el principal. El formulario 2 esta abierto desde antes y a medida que se van llamando turnos, se debería ir actualizando. Si en el formulario 1 creo el formulario 2 y uso el método para updatear desde el form 1 se solucionaría el problema?

Comment: Es exactamente lo que tenes que hacer. Guardar la referencia al formulario 2 en tu formulario 1 y acceder al mismo desde esa referencia.